# UML Class Diagram with Inheritance and Interface

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm trying to understand how can I draw a UML diagram of a program that extends one class and implements another interface. I've made this sketch but I'm not sure if it is correct.

A is a `class` that has some fields and methods and B is an `interface` which has some methods. And finally C is `extending` from A and `implements` B. ( *like public class C extends A implements B in java*)

[image]

Comment: I think that your diagram is correct. http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm

Comment: @RubioRic Not really. The generalization arrow is drawn incorrectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your diagram is almost correct. The left generalization is drawn like a unfilled triangle.

[image]

**Edit**: In Enterprise Architect you can show the generalization also with the general class written in italics top right of the generalizing class:

[image]

Obviously this is a pure Sparxian invention as their support does not have an explanation for its origin.

Comment: I've never seen that general class in italics in the UML spec. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @JimL. I'm using that with Enterprise Architect and they are quite compliant. I'll try to find the source in Superstructures.

Comment: @JimL. It seems that you are right and this notation is an invention of Sparx. I have made an edit to my answer and wi'll ask Sparx for the rationale.